# Class with Generic Type

Tags: c#

I need to create two classes one that takes a T and another that takes a List (I omitted some of the code for sake of simplicity):

```
public class Envelope<T> {
  public T Result { get; private set; }
}

public class Envelope<List<T>> {
  public Paging Paging { get; private set; }
  public List<T> Result { get; private set; } = new List<T>();
}
```

I get the error:

```
Partial declarations of 'TEnvelope<T>' must have the same type parameter names in the same order
```

Is there a way to define these two types of Envelope classes?

Comment: Just rename second class and make type parameter as simple <T>..

Comment: `class Envelope<List<T>>` is invalid syntax. It should be `class Envelope<T>`. But that would mean it has the same name. You have to give it different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare two classes with same name in same namespace. If you do so compiler thinks that's a partial declaration (you can break class into different files in same assembly using partial keyword).

I think that classes design will lead you to problems down the road so I recommend to create two different classes:

```
public class Envelope<T> {
    public T Result { get; private set; }
}

public class Envelopes<T> {
   public Paging Paging { get; private set; }
   public List<T> Results { get; private set; }
}
```

Both of them have different puropse so it's natural to create two different: first one have only one result, second list of results AND paging.

But if you really need to have it that way then settle on one class only:

```
public class Envelope<T> where T : new() {
    public Paging Paging { get; private set; }
    public T Result { get; private set; } = new T();
}
```

Comment: In case of one class approach, as you can see, first class not contains `Paging` property - it will be better to create base generic class with only one `Result` property and another one(`Envelopes`) inherited from this base class with addition `Paging` property: `Envelopes<T> : BaseEnvelope<T> where T : new()` P.S. you forget `()` after `new` token at type parameter constraint.

Comment: Of course it would be better to create two classes that abstract concrete scenario, that's why I said "if you really need". Whole op's approach with one-class-suits-all is wrong IMO but then again I don't know whole context of what's he doing and that's why I showed two possibilities but pointing which one is the way I'd go. As for () after new you're right, thanks for pointing that out.